# Big-O, Omega, Theta and Orders of common functions

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

[image]

Based on this table, is it generally going to be true that for two functions whose most "significant" terms are of the same order that they will be big-Theta each other? And a function of order lower on this table will be big-O ones above it?

Here is the context of my question if it helps:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that all functions corresponding to the same entry in the table will be $\Theta$ of each other.  In particular, $a^x = O(b^x)$ if and only if $|a| \leq |b|$.  I'm not sure about the L-notation bit.

It is true, however, that $f = O(g)$ if $g$ is lower down on the table.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but have a look at (b):
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}} = 0
$$
This means $f(n) = o(g(n))$, i.e. we can pick $c >0$ arbitrarily small, and $\forall c>0 \ \exists \ N(c)\ s.t. \ \forall n>N(c) \ \sqrt{n} < c n^{\frac{2}{3}}$. At the same time $\nexists N(s) \ s.t. \forall n>N(s) \ \sqrt{n} >s n^{\frac{2}{3}}$.Hence $f(n) \neq \Omega (g(n))$.

Here $f(n)$ is the numerator and $g(n)$ is the denominator.

Comment: Ok, right. I have a fairly decent understanding of the formal definition. Lets look at part d of my second image. Since both functions are of the form nlogn can I automatically assume that they are big-Theta eachother?

Comment: Do you mean $a f(n)$ and $b f(n) + c h(n)$ where $h(n) = o(f(n))$? Yes, then LHS = $\Theta$(RHS)

Answer (score 2):

> is it generally going to be true that for two functions whose most "significant" terms are of the same order that they will be big-Theta each other?

Yes, in the following sense.

Assume that $f(n)=h(n)+r(n)$ and $g(n)=k(n)+s(n)$ with $h(n)=\Theta(k(n))$, $r(n)=o(h(n))$ and $s(n)=o(h(n))$. Then indeed $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$.